# Populate database data into program android

Tags: android, database

I actually intended to use my SQLite Browser created database in my android program. I read through some articles and all said to use the path /data/data/com.restaurant.sesame/databases/ . I am a little confused, I can not find the folder in my files? **I don't have data folder or should I create it myself?**

I put in the log to keep track where the program auto terminates and it terminated after it opened the database and claimed that my database "dont have food table" in it. I checked and it only output android_metadata as my only table in my database.

> **My question is Why my database only have 1 table : android_metadata**
>   table only but **no Food table?** What Steps I have missed out?

This is my database info 2 tables
Table 1 : Food (_id,name, price)
Table 2 : android_metadata

I actually followed this link : http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

This is my code for handling the database

```
    package com.restaurant.sesame;

    public class Restaurant {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="Restaurantdb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="Food";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH ="/data/data/com.restaurant.sesame/databases/";

    private static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
    private static Context ourContext = null;
    private DBHelper ourHelper;

    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


        /**
         * Constructor
         * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
         * @param context
         */
        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }   

      /**
         * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
         * */
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if(dbExist){
                //do nothing - database already exist
            }else{

                //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
                   //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }

        }

        /**
         * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
         * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
         */
        private boolean checkDataBase(){

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try{
                String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            }catch(SQLiteException e){

                //database does't exist yet.

            }

            if(checkDB != null){

                checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        /**
         * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
         * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
         * This is done by transfering bytestream.
         * */
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

            //Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = ourContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

            //Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

            //Open the database
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            ourDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

                if(ourDatabase != null)
                    ourDatabase.close();

                super.close();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

            // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
           // You could return cursors by doing "return ourDatabase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
           // to you to create adapters for your views.

    }

    public Restaurant(Context c)
    {   
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public Restaurant open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);

        try {
            ourHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {
            ourHelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        Log.w("my app", "IN getData TOP!!!!");
        String [] columns = new String [] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_PRICE};   
        Log.w("my app", "DDDDDDDDD");
      /*  to test what table in my database
        Cursor c1 = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'" , null);
        String result1="";
        int i =0;
        if(c1!= null){
            c1.moveToFirst();
            result1 =result1 + c1.getString(i);
            Log.w("my app", result1);
            i++;
        }
        Log.w("my app", "AAAAAAAAAA");
        return result1;
        */
             Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result ="";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iPrice = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE);
        Log.w("my app", "IN getData MIDDLE!!!!");
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) +"\t" +
                              c.getString(iName) + "\t" +
                              c.getString(iPrice) + "\n";
        }
        Log.w("my app", "IN getData END!!!!");
        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, what you are expecting from us?

Answer (score 1):

If you are supplying a pre-populated `your_app.db` file to use as a database (as opposed to doing all the `INSERT` statements at start-up or only using user-generated data), you will need to include the database as a raw resource, which looks like more or less what that link is instructing you to do.  I'm guessing your database copying isn't working properly, since the `DBHelper` classes will create the `android_metadata` table if it doesn't already exist.

Is this database going to be read-only?  If so, you should be able to open it in place from your app's raw resources.  There's a chance you could even write it there, but I'm not sure if that's permissible.